# DOMPDF not working with boostrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, dompdf

Ciao, I have to create a pdf file with dompdf, but if i use bootstrap.min.css dompdf not working.
If i remove the files works...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/cms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pagine.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once './fattura.php'; ?>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

The fattura.php file is the html content for pdf

This is the code to generate the content

```
<?php

require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

$filename = 'file_prova';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/cms-contratto/pagine-contratto/contratto.php'); 
pdf_create($html,$filename,'A4','portrait');

function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE)
{
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper,$orientation);
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    i$dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
}
```

Grazie!

Comment: How is it not working? Does the PDF not look right? Or does it not render at all.

Comment: FYI, dompdf does not yet faithfully render bootstrap-based layouts. See here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be that parsing the Bootstrap fonts could be exhausting system resources. See here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/860

Comment: I tried to look at the 2 link, but the problem persists.
If i use bootstrap.css the render does not work :(

Comment: Without more details about what "does not work" means it's hard to diagnose. Any errors? What actually happens? Does the PDF render but doesn't look right? Do you get nothing? Also, for diagnosing problems with dompdf it helps to see the actual HTML being rendered *not* the PHP that creates the HTML.

Comment: Simply with the css of bootsrap, PDF is not generated.
HTML is basic there is no PHP .
What I see is a blank page with no errors

Comment: A blank page probably means there was an error. Anything in your logs? If you can I recommend trying out 0.7.0 beta 3. The updates in that version have made it less likely that a Bootstrap-based layout will fail rendering.